# RestTemplate for GET request with JSON payload

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

I'm trying to create test unit for GET method which requires JSON payload to get result based on provided data in JSON.

I have tried that:

```
   User user = new User();
   user.setUserId(userId);

   ResponseEntity<User> getResponse = restTemplate.exchange(getRootUrl() + "/getUser", HttpMethod.GET, user, User.class);

    assertNotNull(getResponse);
    assertEquals(getResponse.getStatusCode(), HttpStatus.OK);
```

but it throws an error on `exchange` for `user` that object is not suitable.

Comment: What is the rest of your test? What are you returning? is the request successful in the test?

Comment: @DarrenForsythe OP updated. And response is JSON object of `user`

Comment: Are you trying to write junit testcase ?

Comment: @GovindParashar yes, I have done POST, which works fine but can't get GET junit test for GET method with JSON payload

Comment: can you show the code for RestApi which you are consuming?

Answer (score 1):

the [method documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#exchange-java.lang.String-org.springframework.http.HttpMethod-org.springframework.http.HttpEntity-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object...-) is pretty straightforward

> Execute the HTTP method to the given URI template, writing the given request entity to the request, and returns the response as ResponseEntity.
>   URI Template variables are expanded using the given URI variables, if any.

Specified by:
exchange in interface RestOperations
Parameters:
url - the URL
method - the HTTP method (GET, POST, etc)
requestEntity - the entity (headers and/or body) to write to the request may be null)
responseType - the type of the return value
uriVariables - the variables to expand in the template

you need change user to  HttpEntity

> ```
>   HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
>   headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
>   JSONObject parm = new JSONObject();
>    parm.put("user", user);
>    HttpEntity<JSONObject> entity = new HttpEntity<JSONObject>(parm, headers);
> ```

Comment: Current error is `org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: No HttpMessageConverter for [org.json.JSONObject]`

Comment: you need import json jar
https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&ei=Y0d3XOKpE5L3-gTR9aHQDg&q=jsonobject+import+maven&oq=JSONObject+import+&gs_l=psy-ab.3.1.0i203l5j0i30l5.3078.3078..4851...0.0..0.242.242.2-1......0....1..gws-wiz.ZQ0s-UYvUuw

Comment: It looks like `restTemplate.exchange()` for GET method will pass an empty body no matter what.